# Making Emacs push the location to the mark ring on every big movement

Tags: emacs

I would like to ask if there is a general way to make Emacs push the current location to the mark ring before every big movement like scroll down, scroll up one page, jump to line, jump to new buffer, search text..., so that I can jump back to the history easier?

My current solution is to `def-advice` some of the relevant functions (as in the sample code below), but it does not cover all the cases, and I don't know what else I should `def-advice`

Please share your experience about this problem. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
(defun my-set-mark ()
  (interactive)
  (push-mark (point) t nil))

(defadvice find-file (before set-mark activate) (my-set-mark))
(defadvice goto-char (before set-mark activate) (my-set-mark))
(defadvice goto-line (before set-mark activate) (my-set-mark))
(defadvice isearch-update (before set-mark activate) (my-set-mark))
(defadvice beginning-of-buffer (before set-mark activate) (my-set-mark))
(defadvice end-of-buffer (before set-mark activate) (my-set-mark))
```

Comment: I would *not* advice `goto-char` since it is one of the most commonly used functions on a non-interactive basis, and probably *not* `find-file` either.  You may wish to consider using the `pre-command-hook` with a list of functions -- e.g., `(when (memq this-command '(beginning-of-buffer end-of-buffer goto-line)) (push-mark (point) t nil))`

Comment: Might not help, `goto-line`, `beginning-of-buffer` and `end-of-buffer` would leave mark themselves.

Comment: @songyuanyao: no, they don't. I have checked and then have to `defadvice` them.

Comment: Quote from help of `end-of-buffer`, "If Transient Mark mode is disabled, leave mark at previous position, unless a C-u prefix is supplied."

Comment: @songyuanyao: thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1):

This is a hacky solution that should work, but it may slow down Emacs. I'm not sure I'd recommend using it as it's a bit nuclear, but if you want this behaviour to be automatic you probably need a nuclear solution.

This is untested, so it might need tweaking.

```
;; Variable to store the current point
(defvar last-point nil)
(defvar last-buffer nil)
;; What constitutes a "large movement", in characters.
(defvar large-movement 1000)

(defun store-last-point ()
  (setq last-point (point))
  (setq last-buffer (current-buffer)))

(defun magnitude (number)
  ;; Couldn't find a built-in magnitude function. 
  ;; If anyone knows one, feel free to edit.
  (if (>= number 0)
       number
     (- 0 number)))

(defun push-mark-if-large-movement ()
  ;; If point is in the same buffer and has moved 
  ;; significantly, push mark at the original location
  (if (and (eq last-buffer (current-buffer))
           (> (magnitude (- last-point (point))) large-movement))
       (push-mark last-point)))

(add-hook 'pre-command-hook 'store-last-point)
(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'push-mark-if-large-movement)
```

Be aware, this will prevent you from selecting large sections of text using more than one big movement. If you want to fix that, you would need to add a check to the `push-mark-if-large-movement` command (i.e. if mark is active, don't push the mark).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That's quite an hacky solution. However, since it hooks on every command, it is likely to slow down Emacs.

Comment: Yep. It needs to hook to every command to be automatic, though. You can't retroactively check for the old cursor position, and checking if a command moves the point before running would be fairly complicated. It may be more efficient to manually create a list of big movement commands, and add these functions as advice to each one.

Comment: Yeah, I am hooking on a list of few functions. It's works, but it's not general